# vba PowerPoint 2010 open multiple files, copy module and userform, save as .pptm

Tags: vba, save, powerpoint

The title pretty much says.

1. I need to open all the PowerPoint files recursively in a directory (done).
2. I need to copy the Userform and module from an already-open file.
3. I need to resave all the PowerPoint files in their original directories as macro-enabled PowerPoint documents.

For bonus points **how can I ensure that all the files have the same master slides as the original and that the slides are updated when the master changes**.

Here is the code that opens the files. It works.

```
Sub OpenAllFiles()

Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim vFile As Variant
RecursiveDir colFiles, "C:\Users\Debra\Dropbox\School\Mathematics\Notes", "*.pptx", True
For Each vFile In colFiles    
        Presentations.Open (vFile)
Next vFile
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) This looks to be a large task - what have you tried so far beyond this open code? 2) What is the code for `RecursiveDir`? 3) What do you mean *bonus points*?

Comment: RecursiveDir recursively traverses the directory given and returns a collection of filenames. I can open all the files.

Comment: Yes, but you haven't provided the `RecurseDir` code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question as asked (before *bonus*)

This code

- Opens all the files under `strDir`  i.e. *c:\temp*
- Exports a module *Module1* and a userform *UserForm* from the current PPT file
- Saves these files under `strDir` as *pptm* files
- Deletes the original *pptx* file

**Code**

```
Sub OpenAllFiles()
Dim ppPres As Presentation
Dim fName As String
Dim strDir As String
Dim VbComp1
Dim VbComp2
Set VbComp1 = ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1")
Set VbComp2 = ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1")
strDir = "c:\temp\"
VbComp1.Export strDir & "\mod1.bas"
VbComp2.Export strDir & "\uf1.frm"

fName = Dir(strDir & "\*.pptx")
Do While fName <> vbNullString
Set ppPres = Presentations.Open(strDir & "\" & fName, msoFalse)
With ppPres
.VBProject.VBComponents.Import strDir & "\mod1.bas"
.VBProject.VBComponents.Import strDir & "\uf1.frm"
.SaveAs Replace(ppPres.Name, "pptx", "pptm"), ppSaveAsOpenXMLShowMacroEnabled
.Close
'remove original pptx file
Kill Dir(strDir & "\*.pptx")
fName = Dir
End With
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: One again, this looks awesome. I will test it tonight.

Comment: Although this code appeared to work with a few tweaks, the resulting files were corrupt. I suspect this is because of trying to add forms and modules before the file is saved as .pptm. Also the 2nd export line should start VbComp2.export = ....

Answer (score 1):

If you get the reference to the `Presentation` object returned from `Presentations.Open` you can manipulate the opened presentations directly. Otherwise you have to loop through the Presentations object after you open them. When you have a `Presentation` object you can see the `SlideMaster` used for that `Presentation`. As for copying VBA-code, you could try something like http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx or http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/copy-vba-module.php

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    'Declare variables
    Dim oPres As Presentation
    Dim oMaster As Master

    'Get presentation
    Set oPres = Presentations.Open("Gud vilken härlig powerpoint.pptx")

    'Get master
    Set oMaster = oPres.SlideMaster

    'Do something
    Debug.Print oPres.Name
    Debug.Print oMaster.Name

    'Save as macro-ppt
    Call oPres.SaveAs("NEW-FILE-NAME.pptm", ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentationMacroEnabled)

    'Clean up
    Set oMaster = Nothing
    Set oPres = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Having trouble with this. I'm going to repost this as a separate question.